# Date based Query

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g, case

I am trying to get this to run as a test for checking `FISCAL_START` date range.

```
SELECT FISCAL_START,DESCRIPTION,
(
CASE FISCAL_START
WHEN  FISCAL_START = '2014-03-31' THEN  DESCRIPTION
WHEN  FISCAL_START = '2014-09-29' THEN  DESCRIPTION
ELSE 'Test Failed'
END ) 
FROM GL_PERIOD
```

keep getting error that missing key word.

Comment: which db are you working with

Comment: SORRY about that ..it was Oracle 11

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up the `case` *expression* syntax.

What you want is probably:

```
SELECT FISCAL_START, DESCRIPTION,
       CASE WHEN FISCAL_START >= DATE'2014-03-31'
             AND FISCAL_START <= DATE'2014-09-29' THEN DESCRIPTION
            ELSE 'Test Failed'
       END 
FROM GL_PERIOD
```

Which can be simplified as:

```
SELECT FISCAL_START, DESCRIPTION,
       CASE WHEN FISCAL_START BETWEEN DATE'2014-03-31' AND DATE'2014-09-29' THEN DESCRIPTION
            ELSE 'Test Failed'
       END 
FROM GL_PERIOD
```

Comment: Column DESCRIPTION data type?

Comment: Sorry this is now  working without edits.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve now is use the Columns names of FISCAL_START and FISCAL_END like this ... Psuedo Code is this : Select DESCRIPTION from GL_PERIOD where Entry_Date ( which is from a view called WORK and does not have direct link with GL_PERIOD) is between FISCAL_START and FISCAL_END ( which are in the GL_PERIOD table)

Comment: Here you have the answer to your original question. Ask a new question if you want another answer.